# calculating explained variance for each level in lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Forgive me if this question is more in the statistical side than on the computational side, but I'd still appreciate some help.

I have a four level (diad,student,class,school) random slopes and intercept model  and I would like to calculate the explained variance for each level.

```
Random effects:
 Groups                     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 studentid:(classid:school) (Intercept) 0.13415  0.3663                    
                            Arabij      0.10236  0.3199   -0.40            
                            ArabiJewj   0.20673  0.4547   -0.69  0.80      
                            JewiArabj   0.01267  0.1125   -0.95  0.66  0.81
 classid:school             (Intercept) 0.03051  0.1747                    
                            Arabij      0.05207  0.2282   -0.41            
                            ArabiJewj   0.02494  0.1579   -0.35  0.65      
                            JewiArabj   0.04058  0.2015   -0.50  0.67  0.99
 school                     (Intercept) 0.02814  0.1677                    
                            Arabij      0.05182  0.2276   -0.72            
                            ArabiJewj   0.06528  0.2555   -0.84  0.31      
                            JewiArabj   0.04570  0.2138   -0.89  0.39  1.00
 Residual                               0.68517  0.8277
```

Should I sum for each level the total variance of slopes + intercepts + residual and then divide each variance estimate by the number I obtained.

I guess\know that this is probably not the way to do that...

If anyone can offer an explanation or a referral to somewhere that gives a good explanation it will be fantastic.

Comment: I see this as a statistical question more than a coding question. The notion of "total variance", presumably as a denominator for some inferential statistic, is something that you are importing from the classical (non-mixed) linear models framework. The Unofficial Mixed Models FAQ http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq is probably the first place to go. Then pose your amended question to CrossValidated.com.  (Good thing I got my comment in before casting the fifth and final migrate vote.) Please do edit you question to include more explanation about what you propose to do with "total variance".